# Filter Mongo cursor fields to desired array index with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

In the process of learning to use Mongo and PHP, and got stuck with this. 
I have a collection in Mongo with the following structure:

```
array(3){
["timehack"]=>int(..),  
["_id"]=>object..,  
["series"]=>  
array(3){  
    [0]=>int(..),  
    [1]=>int(..),  
    [2]=>int(..)  
}  
}
```

I am trying to query the collection so i get all of the samples with first item in "series", something like:

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->fields(array=>("timehack"=>true, "_id"=>false, "series.0"=>true));
$arr = $cursor->getNext();
var_dump($arr);
```

The resulting series array is empty. How can I get just the desired index? (I realize that I can get all samples in the series then filter with code, but I would like to know how to accomplish this with a query). Thanks.

Comment: Have you successfully been able to run this in the JS shell yet?  I think it would roughly look like: collection.find({}, {"timehack: 1, "_id" : 0, "series.0":1}) - also I would take a look at the $slice command rather than a literal position, see how that works out.

Comment: @AdamC - $slice did the trick! so the shell command would look like: db.collection.find({},{"timehack":1, "_id":0, "series":{$slice:[0,1]}}) - that will return objects with just data series 0. Now my next step is to get this working in the PHP driver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments above you have already confirmed that this works with the $slice operator in the shell.  So, to give you an example of how $slice works in PHP, I refer you to none other than the PHP tests in the driver itself.

Take a look at line 33 in the tests/MongoCollectionTest2.php file on github:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoCollectionTest2.php

The code goes like this:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = new MongoDB($m, "phpunit");
$this->object = $db->selectCollection('c');
...
...
$results = $this->object->find(array(),array("x" => array('$slice' => 3)))->getNext();
```

It looks a little convoluted compared to the shell with a lot of casting as an object going on (if I am reading that right), but hopefully enough to get you started :)

Comment: @AdamC-The PHP API follows the shell pretty close. So I was able to do this:  $cursor = $collection->find(array(), array("timehack"=>true,"_id"=>false,"series"=>array('$slice'=>array(0,1)))); The $slice has to use single quotes, though. Thanks Adam!